# Boxfuse deployment without encrypting AMIs

Tags: cloudcaptain

Is it possible to make a Boxfuse deployment to AWS without encrypting images? Even the smallest Play Framework fused application (~90MB) takes about 5 minutes (as opposed to announced ~50 seconds) to encrypt, not to mention projects of greater size. For that reason it would be interesting to be able to disable encrypting at least for environments where deployments are frequent (QA, test, etc.).
There is a comment somewhere from Boxfuse about choosing AWS regions which are optimised for AMI signing, but I didn't have luck with that. It is still rather slow for my case.

Comment: In which AWS region are you seeing this?

Comment: US, East, N. Virginia